# Retrive Result set in 2D array as a table to display this table in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, multidimensional-array

I have JDBC table which contains huge records and I want to store Result set from selected query into multi-dimensional array and display as a table in jsp page.

Servlet page:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
try {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()); 
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip/test","user","pass");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    out.println(e.getMessage());
}
try {
    OraclePreparedStatement stmt
                    = (OraclePreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(
                            "Select * from MSG");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
    }
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: i want to store result set in 2D array as rows and columns and i create jsp page with table structure to add this array into this page ...

Comment: any help please !!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but basically:

a) crate `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` to store the results.

b) get the number of columns `rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()`

c) for each row crate `ArrayList<Object>`, iterate over colums from row and add them to it.

d) add the row to the results array.

basing on your code it could be something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> resultTable = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

     try {

DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()); con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip/test","user","pass");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
    try {
        OraclePreparedStatement stmt
                = (OraclePreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(
                        "Select * from MSG");

          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(); 
          ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
          int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

          while (rs.next()) {
           ArrayList<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>();
           for (int col=1; col < columnCount) {
               row.add(rs.getObject(col));
           }
           resultTable.add(row);
          }
    } catch ...

    // here you have results rewriten to resultsTable
```

Comment: <form  name="projectform" method="post" action="operationservlet" ></form>
        <form action="/Register" method="post"></form>
        <table>
            <%
                ArrayList arr = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("resultTable");
                String myString = "";
                if (arr.isEmpty() == false) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                        myString = (String) arr.get(i);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Array is empty");
                }
            %>